# Include empty matches when using string.gmatch to split a string in lua 5.1

Tags: regex, lua, string-matching, lua-patterns, lua-5.1

I have a  comma seperated input string that needs to support empty entries. So a string like `a,b,c,,d` should result in a table with 5 entries, where the 4'th is an empty value.

**A simplified example**

```
str="a,b,c,,d"
count=0

for v in string.gmatch(str, '([^,]*)') do
    count = count + 1
end

print(count)
```

This code outputs

> 9

in Lua 5.1, although there are only 5 entries.

I can change the `*` in the regex to `+` - then it reports the 4 entries `a,b,c,d` but not the empty one. It seems that this behaviour has been fixed in Lua 5.2, because the code above works fine in lua 5.2, but I'm forced to find a solution for lua 5.1

#### My current implementation

```
function getValues(inputString)
  local result = {}

  for v in string.gmatch(inputString, '([^,]*)') do
    table.insert(result, v)
  end

  return result
end
```

Any suggestions about how to fix?

Comment: simple workaround: replace the empty positions with a space or "novalue" or whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may append a comma to the text and grab all values using a `([^,]*),` pattern:

```
function getValues(inputString)
  local result = {}

  for v in string.gmatch(inputString..",", '([^,]*),') do
    table.insert(result, v)
  end

  return result
end
```

The output:

```
a
b
c

d
```

Comment: @lhf Negated character classes usually perform better.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local str="a,b,c,,d"
local count=1
for value in string.gmatch(str, ',') do
    count = count + 1
end
print(count)
```

And if you want to get the values, you could do something like

```lua
local function values(str, previous)
    previous = previous or 1
    if previous <= #str then
        local comma = str:find(",", previous) or #str+1
        return str:sub(previous, comma-1), values(str, comma+1)
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in my question that I need the values. I have updated the question accordingly. Would you mind providing an example of how to use this `values` function?

Comment: You can just do `v = {values("a,b,c,,d")}` to get a table with all the values :D